# How can I apply the same stroke drawable to RadioButtons while having a unique background image for each?

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

I have a series of `RadioButton`s in a `RadioGroup` each one has a unique `android:background` image. I would like to remove the default circular stroke and instead have a rectangular stroke that changes colors when selected.

I have a shape XML that defines a red stroke and another shape XML that defines a white stroke. Then I have a selector XML defining one as checked and one not.

I can only get my selector XML to appear when applied to `android:background` which seems like it would require unique drawables for every single button. When applied to `android:button` it doesn't appear.

What is the correct way of applying a single drawable for a series of `RadioButton`s while having unique `android:background`s for each?

Comment: Stick each RadioButton in a FrameLayout and put the background image on the layout?

Comment: unfortunately that doesnt work. This seems to make each button independent to the others in the group.